# How to type a function similar to lodash "bindKey" in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to make a function that is essentially a short syntax to `obj.func.bind(obj)` so it would work like this:

```
const bound = <...>(obj: ..., fnKey: ...) : ... => obj[fnKey].bind(obj);

const obj = {
  a: "abc",
  b() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}

const f = bound(obj, "b"); //would be ideal if intellisense shows all keys with function value on second argument
f(); //typed correctly
```

I tried many options, one of them is:

```
function bound<
    K extends string,
    F extends (...args: any[]) => any,
    T extends {[key in K]: F}
>(thisObj: T, fnKey: K): (...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F> {
    const fn : F = thisObj[fnKey];
    return fn.bind(thisObj);
}
```

But non of them seems to work as the return value is typed incorrectly:

```
const obj = {
    a: "abc",
    foo() {
        console.log(this.a);
    },
};

const f = bound(obj, "foo"); //(...args: any[]) => any
```

Also, if I try to avoid any and specify `F extends (...args: never[]) => unknown` I get ts error `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<F>'`.

@types/lodash [left this function basically untyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/46cd17037ac5399364b0a59511d646c0dd56165a/types/lodash/common/function.d.ts#L109C1-L109C84).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple generic will do the trick. I just added another conditional to asure a `keyof T` is actually callable.

```
const bound = <T extends Record<any, any>, F extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  fnKey: T[F] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? F : never
): T[F] => obj[fnKey].bind(obj);

const obj = {
  a: "abc",
  b() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
};

const f = bound(obj, "b");
f(); // "abc"
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARiArmAJjAvDAPAFRgUwA8p9UIYAlfUAJxSwEMwBPAGhieYD52AxA4qRTkA1vmYgAZjBxcAFAFgAUDBgg4AKwBcM1stWSwAaXE6cAbV4BdASTIw5AOmcMaAcwg7O5qwEoMXBwsMAD8MPw6YPgAbvg0yr5mljbogeoa5oYmzFaOcACWqHLpvgDcysqgkLDpGDAA3vocOgBEDHDALXoq8HL+jT2qVRAgADb4jqMgbnJQABb5EI4MZU0Avspr5UqV4NAw0pgIyCjFmuwtcC2rSpJ9pTAA9I8wbR0tQA)